# Database size limit of derby and SQLIte

Tags: system.data.sqlite

I have  Rmi Server  in which i am using SQLite database .

But client from different machine need to access the database.

Shall i use SQLite or Derby

Extra details:

- We are trying with 100 users i put this lightweight database in remote machine which have 96 GB RAM

Please guide

Comment: Right we are trying with 100 users i put this lightweight database in remote machine which have 96 GB RAM  .

Comment: From different system can client can access dery or Sqlite i have confusion

Comment: If you are using Java, a Java embedded database seems to be a better fit. I would prefer HSQLDB or H2 over Derby.